# My VBA code for extracting information from between brackets is returning a type mismatch, but I'm not quite sure why.

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script written to separate characters between "<" and ">" in a range.

What I have is:

```
 Dim Rng As Range
 Dim i As Long
 i = 2
 While i <= 20000

 Set Rng = Range("B" & i)

 If InStr(Rng, "<") = 0 Then
 i = i + 1

 ElseIf InStr(Rng, "<") > 0 Then
 Rng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=mid(left(RC[-1],find(" > ",RC[-1])-1),find(" < ",RC[-1])+1,len(RC[-1]))"
 i = i + 1
 Else: i = i + 1
 End If
 Wend
 End Sub
```

This works well when I substitute the long formula with something simpler. Yet I'm getting a Type Mismatch when I run this. I have a feeling that I'm missing something very simple. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"` quotes inside a `"quoted"` string need to be escaped (by doubling them) if they are not how would the compiler know where the string truly ended?

```
FormulaR1C1 = "=mid(left(RC[-1],find("" > "",RC[-1])-1),find("" < "",RC[-1])+1,len(RC[-1]))"
```

(In your current code `<` & `>` are outside the string so are interpreted as the GT/LT operators)

Comment: I did not think of that. Thanks a million! :)

Comment: You could also use a character code for the quotes. In your string, you can use ...find(" & chr(34) & ",RC... instead of the double quotes. I don't think there's much difference, but I personally do it because it is easier for me to separate what quotes begin and end strings and what quotes belong inside strings.

Answer (score 1):

Alex already gave the answer
I only add this to reduce the code, if of interest

```
Sub test()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 2
While i <= 20000
    Set Rng = Range("B" & i)
    If InStr(Rng, "<") > 0 Then
        If InStr(Rng, "<") > 0 Then Rng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=mid(left(RC[-1],find("">"",RC[-1])-1),find(""<"",RC[-1])+1,len(RC[-1]))"
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```